# Kotlin: Visibility of static nested Java class declared inside a non-visible class

Tags: kotlin

Using java my static-nested java class is visible, but using Kotlin it is not. See my example below. Is there a good reason it is not allowed, or is it a bug? And are there any workarounds so that I can extend `NestedStaticClass` from Kotlin?

I have a package-private java class containing the static-nested class

```
package javapackage;

class HiddenClass {
    public static class NestedStaticClass {}
}
```

`HiddenClass` is extended by a public class.

```
package javapackage;

public class VisibleClass extends HiddenClass{}
```

From my java class extending `VisibleClass`, I can see `NestedStaticClass` (It compiles)

```
package otherpackage;

import javapackage.VisibleClass;

public class JavaClass extends VisibleClass {

    public static class C4 extends NestedStaticClass {}

    public JavaClass() {
        new NestedStaticClass();
    }
}
```

But from Kotlin this does not work. I get the compile error: "Unresolved reference NestedStaticClass"

```
package otherpackage

import javapackage.VisibleClass

class KotlinClass() : VisibleClass() {
    class C1() : NestedStaticClass()

    init {
        val v = NestedStaticClass()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a semantic issue. Java really resolves to HiddenClass.NestedStaticClass and you could always just reference it the same way in Kotlin.

Comment: referencing `HiddenClass.NestedStaticClass` also does not work

Comment: are you going to move all classes to Kotlin or keep java and extend with kotlin?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example and it works with `HiddenClass.NestedStaticClass` for me

Comment: The issue is that Kotlin before M15 does not support inheriting nested classes, this will be changed soon. But, incidentally, it won't support deriving a public class from a non-public one.

Comment: Cool, I will look forward to M15.

Comment: So Kristian, do you want to write an answer that shows how this now works in Kotlin 1.0 betas?

Comment: M15 did not solve the problem. As of 1.0.0-beta-4584 the example is still not compiling.

Comment: @DamianPetla. Using `HiddenClass.NestedStaticClass` is not working for me. The two java classes `HiddenClass` and `VisibleClass` must not be changed, and `KotlinClass` must extend `VisibleClass`.